# How to bind a function to an html button without a form in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm new to Django and I need to bind a function from python to a button using onclick from a file views.py. I saw a lot of discussions where they do this with forms, but I want to do without them

index.html:

```
<div class="submit">
      <button type="button" name="submit" onclick="">Get Info</button>
</div>
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    def index(request):

        return render(request, 'index.html')

    def get_info():
        print("It works")
```

Need to bind get_info()

Comment: You cannot access a function from jinja template without adding `urlpattern`. So, add your function to `urlpattern`, then call it like @LordPokerFace's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your views directly,if are added in urls.py

```
<div class="submit">
      <button type="button" name="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'get_info' %}">Get Info</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fetche](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) in **Javascript** to send HTTP request to the URL you want,
in **views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST': #or what method you have choosen 
   get_info()
```